# How do I use C++ keyword "this" along with member function "operator="?

Tags: c++, class, reference, operator-overloading

The question stems from [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/). A class that represents a two-dimensional vector is defined as below,

```
class CVector {
  public:
    int x,y;
    CVector () {}
    CVector (int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    CVector& operator = (const CVector&);
};

CVector& CVector::operator= (const CVector& param)
{
  x=param.x;
  y=param.y;
  return *this;
}
```

My question is how do I use `operator =`? For example,

```
CVector a, b;
b.x = 1;
b.y = 3;
CVector & c = a = b;
```

My confusion now is that suppose there are two CVector objects `a` and `b`, and if I execute `c=a=b`(equivalently to `c=a.operator=(b)`), then is it true that two things are done here: first, `a` have the same `x` and `y` as `b`; second, `c` is set as an alias/reference of `a`? I would appreciate any examples.

Comment: It's just a multiple assignment. `c=a=b` first executes `a=b`, then `c=a`. For a long while I favored return of `void` from `operator=` so as to avoid such questionable constructions, but then I learned that standard library containers require that a copy assignment operator for a container item returns a reference to the object assigned to.

Comment: Still confused. I wonder are you defining `c` as `CVector & c;` but for `a` and `b`, they are defined as `CVector`? Secondly, is it true that `a` and `b` are different objects (although `x` and `y` are the same after the execution) but `c` and `a` are the same object (have same address) due to `return *this;`?@Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: Are you suggesting if we just want to set `a.x` and `a.y` equal to `b.x` and `b.y`, then we can just use `a=b` without bothering a multiple assignment?@Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: One last question is: since `c` is a reference type rather than type `CVector`, the `=` symbol in `c=a` is just a normal assignment sign, but the `=` symbol in `a=b` is special and only copies values of member `x` and `y` from the `CVector` object after the `=` sign (here `b`)?@Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: You need to provide a **complete but minimal example** that readers can try out directly. This thing about `c` being a reference is not evident in the question. And it's not clear whether it's intended or a misconception. For now voted to close as lacking such reproducible example.

Comment: Re-edited my question.@Cheersandhth.-Alf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how did you declare `c`.

if `c` is just `CVector`, then the expression

```
a=b;
```

returns `CVector&`. then, since `c` is a *full fledged object* and not a reference, the compiler is looking for the method `XXX operator = (CVector&)`.

now, `CVector` doesn't have any `XXX operator = (CVector&)` method (*note that the method gets a reference, not a const reference*), but is has `CVector& operator = (const CVector&)` (a method which gets *const* reference).

is the casting between reference to const reference is allowed? yes, so the method `CVector& operator = (const CVector&)` will be called.

now, `c` has the values of `a` and `b`. again, `c` is *an object*.

now, if you declared `c` as `CVector&` or `const CVector&` (a reference), then the expression

```
CVector& c = a = b;
```

will alias `c` as a, because you assigned the reference returned by `a.operator =(b)` to yet another reference.

to sum things up, there is a difference between
`CVector c = a = b;`
and 
`CVector& c = a = b;` , the first will "copy" the data of `a` to a real object `c` while the last will alias `c` as `a`.